# METER UNA VARIABLE EN UN STR

Tags: python

Veran tengo un programa de una libreria cuyo objetivo en este caso es prestar libros y dependiendo de que libro sea te lo mueva a una carpeta que se llame prestamos con el siguiente codigo:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
print(os.listdir("..\PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA\libros"))
libro=input("¿Que libro deseas prestar? ")
ruta = os.getcwd() + os.sep
origen = ruta + ("..\PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA\libros\libro")
destino = ruta + ('..\PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA\prestamos')
if os.path.exists(origen):  
    ruta = shutil.move(origen, destino)
    print('El directorio ha sido movido a', ruta)
else:
    print('El directorio origen no existe')
```

Donde quiero meterle en la variable origen la otra variable libro, perdonen mi ignorancia si no se puede hacer o si tengo algun que otro error

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es substituir \\***libro** por la cadena ingresada con `input` y asociada a la variable libro? Una opción es concatenar igual que haces con `rut + (...)` Aunque hay formas más correctas ¿O buscas otra cosa?

Comment: Lo que quiero es sustituir en la ruta de origen: ..\PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA\libros\*libro* por lo que se escriba en el input de la variable libro

Comment: ¿y por qué no eliminas lo que dice libro y simplemente la concatenas?

Comment: `origen = ruta + ("..\PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA\libros\" + libro)` no has probado con eso ?

Comment: ya lo he probado y me dice que no se encuentra el directorio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por norma general puedes unir cadenas de varias formas, aunque no deberías usarlo para formar rutas (ver abajo):

- Concatenado con operador  `+`:

  ```
  origen = ruta + ("/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/libros/") + libro + ".txt"
  ```

  La concatenación encadenada de más de dos cadenas debe evitarse por norma general. Esto se debe a que es muy ineficiente ya que al ser objetos inmutables, cada concatenación crea un nuevo objeto `str`.
- Formateo de cadenas:

  ```
  origen = f"{ruta}/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/libros/{libro}.txt" # f-strings Python >= 3.6
  ```

  ---

  ```
  origen = "{}/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/libros/{}.txt".format(ruta, libro)
  ```

  ---

  ```
  origen = "%s/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/libros/%s.txt" % (ruta, libro)
  ```
- Usando `str.join`:

  ```
  origen = "".join((ruta, "/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/libros/", libro, ".txt"))
  ```

Ahora bien, usar concatenado o formateado de cadenas para construir rutas debe evitarse generalmente. Es relativamente sencillo cometer algún error, la forma correcta es dejar el trabajo a métodos pensados para ello `os.path.join` o a `pathlib.PurePath.joinpath` (Python >= 3.4).

```
import pathlib

libro = input("¿Que libro deseas prestar? ")
ruta = pathlib.Path.cwd()
origen = ruta.joinpath("/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/libros", libro).with_suffix(".txt")
destino = ruta.joinpath('/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/prestamos', libro).with_suffix(".txt")
```

---

```
import os

libro = input("¿Que libro deseas prestar? ")
ruta = os.getcwd()
origen = os.path.join(ruta, "/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/libros/", libro + ".txt")
destino = os.path.join(ruta, '/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/prestamos', libro + ".txt")
```

Concatenar `ruta` (directorio de trabajo actual) con la ruta relativa `../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/` es realmente redundante. No necesitas para nada ruta en este caso, al usar la ruta relativa indicas que `PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA` es una carpeta situada en el mismo fichero padre que contiene la carpeta en la que está tu script (si no has modificado previamente el directorio de trabajo de este claro).

---

> No uses `\` dentro de cadenas que especifiquen rutas, incluso en Windows. Dicho carácter es usado para denotar secuencias de escape (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`, etc) por lo que puedes terminar con rutas inválidas. Usa `/` que es universal, escapar la barra con `\\` o usar cadenas crudas `r"ruta\a\algo"` pueden funcionar pero dan problemas en casos concretos también.

Comment: Vale, ahora agrego lo de la extensión. No concatenes, incluye el ".txt" en el formato. Aunque insisto en que uses os.path.join por ejemplo para generar la ruta. Espera un momento que voy a editar incluyendo lo de la extensión.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias FJSevilla al final hice esto:

```
origen = "{}/../PROGRAMA-LIBRERIA/libros/{}".format(ruta, libro) + ".txt"
```

Comment: Si querias decir algo agregando algo a la respuesta, hubieras dejado un comentario en la misma. La seccion respuestas es para respuestas. Y esto ya estaba respondido antes ;)